# Log4j get Appender from configfile by name without using logger

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I would like to retrieve all the appenders from my log4j.xml by name to my Java class. there is no logger that has all appenders attached Because I cannot change the log4j.xml. Is there any way to retrieve those appenders? Some appenders aren't attached to any Logger. searching the internet it seemed not to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe this code will help you:

```
static Set<Appender> getAllAppenders() {
    Set<Appender> allAppenders = new HashSet<>();
    LoggerRepository repository = LogManager.getLoggerRepository();
    Enumeration<Logger> loggers = repository.getCurrentLoggers();
    while (loggers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Logger logger = loggers.nextElement();
        Enumeration<Appender> appenders = logger.getAllAppenders();
        while (appenders.hasMoreElements()) {
            allAppenders.add(appenders.nextElement());
        }
    }
    return allAppenders;
}
```

Comment: sadly it wont as there are appenders which aren't attached to any loggers.